# how can i draw dynamic highchart. the y-axis and the number of charts are dynamic from json

Tags: angularjs, json, highcharts

im new in angular js and i need to use highchart in my angular page . the problem is that i must draw chart with dynamic data from json and the number of charts will be dynamic too ,  maybe it should draw 3 or 4 different chart from one json . I searched alot but couldnt solve my problem. 
this code works but show the data in one chart in different series. I need to show each series in different charts, and in this case the json send 4 data but it will be changed .

```js
 1. List item

 $scope.draw_chart = function(){
     Highcharts.chart('container2', {
         chart:{
             type: 'spline',
             animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
             marginRight: 10,
             events: {
                 load: function () {
                     var this_chart = this;
                     $scope.ws = ngSocket('ws://#');
                     $scope.ws.onOpen(function () {
                     });
                     var k = 0 ;
                     var time=0;
                     $scope.points_avarage = [];
                     $scope.ws.onMessage(function (message) {
                         listener(JSON.parse(message.data));
                         var z = JSON.parse(message.data);
                         var line_to_draw = z.result.length;
                         var j = 0 ;
                         for(i=0 ; i < line_to_draw*2 ; i+=2)
                         {
                             $scope.data_to_draw[i] = {
                                 name : z.result[j][0]['name'] ,
                                 y : z.result[j][0]['rx-bits-per-second']
                             }
                             $scope.data_to_draw[i+1] = {
                                 name : z.result[j][0]['name'] ,
                                 y : z.result[j][0]['tx-bits-per-second']
                             }

                             j++;
                         }


                    
                         this_chart.series[0].name= $scope.data_to_draw[0].name;
                         this_chart.series[1].name= $scope.data_to_draw[1].name;
                         this_chart.series[2].name= $scope.data_to_draw[2].name;
                         this_chart.series[3].name= $scope.data_to_draw[3].name;

                    
                         for(i=0; i < line_to_draw*2; i++) {
                             var x = (new Date()).getTime();  // current time
                             var y =  parseInt($scope.data_to_draw[i].y);
                             this_chart.series[i].addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                         
                          
                         }

                     });
                     var d = new Date().toTimeString();
                 }
             }
         },
         global: {
             useUTC: false
         },
         title: {
             text: 'Live data'
         },
         xAxis: {
             type: 'datetime'//,
            
         },
         yAxis: {
             title: {
                 text: 'Value'
             },
             plotLines: [{

                width: 1,
                 color: '#808080'
             }
            ]
         }
        

        plotOptions: {
             series: {
                 marker: {
                    enabled: false
                 }

             }
         },

         series: [{
            
             data: (function () {

                 var data = [],
                     time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                     i;

                 for (i = -5; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                     data.push({
                         x: time ,
                         y: 0
                     });
                 }
                 return data;
             }())
         },
             {
                 
                 data: (function () {
                     var data = [],
                         time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                         i;

                     for (i = -5; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                         data.push({
                             x: time ,
                             y: 0
                         });
                     }
                    return data;
                }())
             },
             {
                
                 data: (function () {
                     var data = [],
                         time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                         i;

                     for (i = -5; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                         data.push({
                            x: time ,
                            y: 0
                         });
                     }
                     return data;
                 }())
             },
             {
                
                 data: (function () {
                     var data = [],
                         time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                         i;

                     for (i = -5; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                         data.push({
                            x: time ,
                            y: 0
                         });
                     }
                     return data;
                 }())
             }

         ]
     });



 };
```

```html
<div id="containet" ng-init="draw_chart()"></div>
```

Comment: You're going to need a unique `<div>` container for each of your charts, and each of them must have unique IDs so that your Highcharts code will know where to render them. That will ensure that the data is placed in the relevant chart.

Comment: As an addition to Mikes comment, you may look into synchronized charts demo provided by Highcharts, they are making their charts dynamically depending on number of series. Here you can find simplified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezahxtk4/1/